# Why doesn't this array_unique work as expected?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, array-unique

Can anybody tell me why this doesn't work as expected?

```
<?php
      $merchant_string = '123-Reg|Woolovers|Roxio|Roxio|BandQ|Roxio|Roxio|Big Bathroom Shop|Roxio|Robert Dyas|Roxio|Roxio|PriceMinister UK|Cheap Suites|Kaspersky|Argos|Argos|SuperFit|PriceMinister UK|Roxio|123-Reg';      

      $merchant_array = explode('|', $merchant_string); 

      for($i = 0; $i<count($merchant_array); $i++)
      {
            $merchant_array = array_unique($merchant_array);

            echo $merchant_array[$i] . '<br />';
      }
?>
```

The results I get is:

```
Woolovers
Roxio

BandQ


Big Bathroom Shop

Robert Dyas
```

All I want is the duplicates gone :|

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you should be calling it before the loop since it only needs to be filtered once.

Second, keys are preserved when you use `array_unique()`, so PHP is attempting to loop through no-longer-existent indices in your array, and may miss some out at the end as well because `count($merchant_array)` now returns a smaller value. You need to reset the keys first (using `array_values()`), then loop it.

```
  $merchant_array = array_values(array_unique($merchant_array));

  for($i = 0; $i<count($merchant_array); $i++)
  {
        echo $merchant_array[$i] . '<br />';
  }
```

Alternatively, use a foreach loop to skip the `array_values()` call:

```
  $merchant_array = array_unique($merchant_array);

  foreach ($merchant_array as $merchant) {
        echo $merchant . '<br />';
  }
```

Comment: Woah... Thanks so much for the explanation and code! Works like a treat.